# How to configure used GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

So i finally switched from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) recently and now i'm missing some features....

So the Setup:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- GPU Onboard: Intel UHD 630
- GPU PCI: Nvidia GTX 1080 Ti
- Installed Driver-Version: nvidia 440.64

Monitors:

- 1x Left-Monitor (Onboard)
- 1x Center 4k-Monitor (Nvidia-Card)
- 1x Right-Monitor (Onboard)

So i recently figured out (by using nvtop and intel_gpu_top) that *every* process is running on the Nvidia-card - even those, whose windows are on the Monitors attached to the Onboard-GPU.

What i want is to either set monitors to specific GPUs or process to use specific GPUs - or is there even a smarter way to solve this problem?